# Facebook chatbot send back repeatedly Django

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am beginner in django and facebook bot. I have doing facebook chatbot with python and I have a small code to send message back to facebook.

```
def post_facebook_message(fbid, recevied_message):

    post_message_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=%s'%PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
    response_msg = json.dumps({"recipient":{"id":fbid}, "message":{"text":recevied_message}})
    status = requests.post(post_message_url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},data=response_msg)
```

I call that method from other method (let say method A). If it got error in method A, it always call post_facebook_message again and again (it never stop).

Part of method A is shown below. I don't use for-loop to send message also.

```
  objTwo = TwoCharacters.objects.filter(lucky_number=first_two_letters, times=inputTimes,lucky_alphabet=inputAlphabet).first()
                    if objTwo is None:
                        post_facebook_message(facebookSenderID, "Some text")
```

Comment: What is method A? Is it view? Can you add full code please?

Comment: Method A is for receiving post data from webhook. It is quite long. From same data, sometimes it repeat , but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Most likely the webhook sends the same data again to your script. You need to answer incoming webhook requests with status code 200, or else Facebook will think something went wrong and try and send the same stuff again.

Comment: Ahh..you are correct. It make sense. Let me try again